# meaning- a cat is a suck

Tags: meaning, canadian-english

People say this when a cat likes cuddling, eg. he's a big suck. I don't know the exact meaning. I couldn't find an appropriate meaning from dictionaries. Or maybe I'm looking up the wrong word (different spelling, same pronunciation).

It could be a local use, I'm in Ontario.

Comment: Could it possibly be *suck-up*?

Comment: I added the `canadian-english` tag, as it seems to be specific to that region.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "...is a suck" is a non-standard idiom, as can be seen on this [Google nGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is%20a%20suck%2Che%20is%20a%20suck%2Cshe%20is%20a%20suck&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20a%20suck%3B%2Cc0).  In over 200 years of English language books to search, "he/she is a suck" cannot be found, and there's barely any instances of "is a suck" at all.

That said, even non-standard idioms can typically be understood by context-- otherwise new idioms could not be created.  In this case, the context is defining the meaning: you should think of a baby suckling on a teat.

There is a similar definition found on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suck#Noun).

> suck (plural sucks)
>
> 3. (Canada) A weak, self-pitying person; a person who won't go along, especially out of spite; a crybaby or sore loser.
> 4. A sycophant, especially a child.

Comment: I'm quite familiar with the slang noun *suck*. Perhaps because I'm Canadian . . .

Comment: Often pronounced "sook", with another version being "a little sooky-baby".